# Django Like count is not incrementing

Tags: python, django

I added a like button to my site and it gets highlighted when clicked on it but does not increment the number of likes or shows the count in the admin. I am not understanding what is the mistake I have done. Please help me to solve this. My code is as follows.

### models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

### views.py

```
@login_required
def about(request,pk):
    context = {}
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post_id = post.pk
    liked = False
    if request.session.get('has_liked_' + str(post_id), liked):
        liked = True
        print("liked {}_{}".format(liked, post_id))
    context = {'post': post, 'liked': liked}
    return render(request, 'imagec/about.html', {'post': post})



@login_required()
def like_post(request):
    liked = False
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        if request.session.get('has_liked_'+post_id, liked):
            print("unlike")
            if post.likes > 0:
                likes = post.likes - 1
                try:
                    del request.session['has_liked_'+post_id]
                except KeyError:
                    print("keyerror")
        else:
            print("like")
            request.session['has_liked_'+post_id] = True
            likes = post.likes + 1
    post.likes = likes
    post.save()
    return HttpResponse(likes, liked)
```

### urls.py

```
url(r'like_post/$', imagec_views.like_post, name='like_post'),
```

### about.html

```
<p>

    <strong id="like_count">{{ post.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <input type="button" onclick="jQuery(this).toggleClass('active')" data-post_id="{{post.id}}" id="likes" value ='Like'>
{% endif %}

</p>
```

### base.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/blog-ajax.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/blog-ajax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = {% static "js/ajax-blog.js" %}> </script>

<script src = {% static "js/jquery-3.js" %}> </script>
```

### ajax-blog.js

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    $.get('/imagec/like_post/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
    });
});
```

Thank You

Comment: Are sure the control is coming to ajax code? If so then like_post view?

Comment: Better practise is to use post not get, because your are changing db fields

Answer (score 1):

You can debug it by using `console.log` in `JS` side and `print` in `Python` side.

**ajax-blog.js**

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    console.log("Post id to be send " + postid);
    $.get('/imagec/like_post/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               console.log("data received: "+data);
               $('#like_count').html(data);
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def about(request,pk):
    context = {}
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post_id = post.pk
    liked = False
    if request.session.get('has_liked_' + str(post_id), liked):
        liked = True
        print("liked {}_{}".format(liked, post_id))
    context = {'post': post, 'liked': liked}
    return render(request, 'imagec/about.html', {'post': post})

@login_required()
def like_post(request):
    liked = False
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        if request.session.get('has_liked_'+post_id, liked):
            print("unlike")
            if post.likes > 0:
                likes = post.likes - 1
                try:
                    del request.session['has_liked_'+post_id]
                except KeyError:
                    print("keyerror")
        else:
            print("like")
            request.session['has_liked_'+post_id] = True
            likes = post.likes + 1
    post.likes = likes
    print("updated liked ", post.likes)
    post.save()
    return HttpResponse(likes, liked)
```

And check the console prints.

Other than that, there are two main suggestions from my end,

- don't use get method to update a value in database
- don't use sessions to save a flag that if a user liked a post. That logic might bug you
  in the future.

Comment: Thank You sir! It is not incrementing and updating in the front end.